# TTL for every table in database

Tags: clickhouse, ttl

I have a Clickhouse db, for logs. I want to store last day of them. And I have some kind of mechanism which aggregates logs by `app_name`. It simply creates a table in my db for app and pushes logs in table related to this app. So the main question how I can specify TTL for every table which will be created in db

I have done this manualy by basic usage of ttl [like this](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/ttl/). But for whole db i can't find anything

Comment: you should specify TTL when you create a table in `create table` statement.

Comment: The main problem, that table creation is not on me. Let's say I can't modify it this way

Comment: Then your only option is to create an automation which adds TTL regularly to new tables (tables without TTL)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set TTL at a db level - either table or column level only https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree#table_engine-mergetree-ttl

You'll need to either schedule ALTER commands or modify your table creation logic.

Comment: Please, use link formatting: `[link](url)`